# Configure OpenCL under Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, opencl, nvidia

How can I install OpenCL drivers under Cygwin?

For example, OpenCL under linux normally checks the /etc/OpenCL/vendors list for links to ICD drivers (e.g. on Linux, nvidia.icd references libnvidia-opencl.so.1), but since Cygwin doesn't have any Nvidia or OpenCL package, I'm assuming I'll have to set the links up manually.

I do have the Windows Nvidia CUDA dev kit installed on the same machine, but it's not obvious whether one of those files should be the one to link to.

[Note that I've already built the OpenCL loader implementation libopencl.a from coprthr, so that part is done - it's just figuring out how to reference the ICD]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile a C/C++ OpenCL program on Windows using Cygwin or MinGW you need to:

- Make sure the OpenCL headers are on the include path. You can download them [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/).
- Link against a static OpenCL library (libopencl.a), which you already have.

To run the program, it needs to find the dynamic OpenCL library DLL. The NVidia driver usually installs it at C:\Windows\System32.

This works for me.

Comment: yes this worked: Just create a text file called `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd` with the contents `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/nvopencl.dll`

Comment: Similarly for AMD cards, create a text file called `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amd.icd` with the contents `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/amdocl64.dll`

Comment: how did you setup the static library ?

Comment: @RonanTarikDrevon, please be more specific.

Comment: @faken I actually downloaded on sourceforge as I am not familiar with creating static libraries on cygwin for windows executable but would be happy to know about it

Comment: @RonanTarikDrevon, I use CMake, it does all the hard work for me. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772887/cmake-creating-a-static-library) answer and the longer CMake documentation about [creating a library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html), static or shared.

Comment: Static libraries on windows have the .lib extension not .a

Comment: Does anyone know how can I configure Intel HD Graphics 520 GPU? I have tried to install several packages (Intel CPU runtime for OpenCL Applications for Windows OS, OpenCL runtime for Inter Core), but I do not know which dll I should refer in /etc/OpenCL/vendors.